# Can you tell moment.js what time zone a value is in?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im currently working in an application where users can set their own time zones.

In this case the user's time zone is set to

```
{
  "value": "Africa/Accra",
  "label": "Africa/Accra"
}
```

We then hit an api for times an action has been performed, all the times come back as GMT.

```
2020-04-02 16:24
```

Is there a way to tell moment.js that the initial `2020-04-02 16:24` value is GMT?

I've been reading around and it seems like i need to manually set the offset depending on what the users timezone is? But wasnt sure if this was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For named timezones instead of numeric values you can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) and the `.tz()` function.
You should convert the date-time string `2020-04-02 16:24` to a moment object first.

```
moment('2020-04-02 16:24').tz('Africa/Accra').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This got me to where I needed to go!
I ended up using 

moment.utc('2020-04-02 16:24').tz('Africa/Accra').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')


Works like a charm